# Architecture behind Azure Web Apps for Linux with Node.js

Tags: azure, azure-web-apps

I'm wondering what the underlying architecture looks like for Azure Web Apps for Linux with Node.js. I can't seem to find any information on this in the documentation

I'm curious about things like whether Node sits behind Nginx or Apache, is there any caching layer, is Node.js cluster being used, etc.

What does the architecture look like?

Comment: Based on my knowlege, Node JS is installed on Linux platform, not like Webapp is installed on Windows platform, it will has better compatibility for some app. If you local apps run on a linux platform, it will a good choice for you. Also, you could ssh to it, please refer to this [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-linux-ssh-support).

Answer (score 3):

Web App on Linux enables customers to run their web apps natively on a Linux platform. This allows for better application compatibility for certain kinds of applications and makes it easier to migrate existing web apps hosted on a Linux platform elsewhere onto Azure App Services. More information about this please refer to this link:[Introduction to Azure Web App on Linux](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-linux-intro).

Architecture behind Azure Web APP for Linux, you could refer to this [blog](http://itnerd.space/2016/11/02/azure-app-service-architecture-3-app-service-on-linux/).

1.Web App is deployed on Apache 2.4 on Debian

2.Web App on Linux are deployed in Docker containers

[image]

Comment: @sg Based on my knowlege, Node JS is installed on Linux platform, not like Webapp is installed on Windows platform, it will has better compatibility for some app. If you local apps run on a linux platform, it will a good choice for you.

Comment: @sg Sorry for my mistake, I had update my answer and add detailed information.

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let me know if you would like further assistance.

Comment: @sg If it is helpful for you, don't forget to accept it as an answer. It will help more people, thanks.